# Default selected option not being selected when populating by API

Tags: vue.js

Vue 3.4.21

I am populating a select via an API call. It's working fine, but I want a default option in my select and I want it selected by default. I'm trying this to no avail:

```
    <select id="service"  v-model="selectedService">
          <option selected>Select a Service</option>
          <option v-for="(item, index) in services" :value="item.id" :key="index">
                            {{ item.name }}
                          </option>
        </select>
```

what's happening is the first option is not selected. The html shows this:

```
         <option>Select a Service</option>
```

instead of this:

```
         <option selected>Select a Service</option>
```

How do I make the first option selected when dynamically populating my dropdown select? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected` attribute can not override v-model. You need to set the v-model to the value that matches your default option. An example is shown in the Vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms#select)

You can edit your default option to have an empty string value and initialize `selectedService` with the same empty string value.

```js
const selectedService = ref('')
```

```html
<select id="service"  v-model="selectedService">
  <option value="">Select a Service</option>
  <option v-for="(item, index) in services" :value="item.id" :key="index">
    {{ item.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was so close. I had selectedService = ref({}) instead of ref(''). Thank you for this